# Power source choice for sensitive applications. USB cleanup vs wall wart step down

Tags: power-supply, usb, power-filtering

When designing a board with a rather sensitive IC that runs on 5V and a goal of minimizing external components.

Does it make more sense to power everything from USB with thorough filtering, or rather accept the need for an "extra" part and use a higher Voltage wall wart and get an already quite clean source from a voltage regulator?

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, USB power--despite the fairly generous 10% tolerance allowed in the spec--is frequently out of spec.  You're better off regulating your own, although a decent buck/boost on your USB supply might do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need both L+C filtering before the LDO, and use a high-current (high iddq) LDO.

Only a fast LDO will regulate the high frequency ripple to be near zero output ripple;

And a fast LDO requires high internal current.

That is, don't expect 1ua or 10ua iddq from the LDO.

Be careful with L+C filtering **after** the LDO; the components are key to stable feedback regulation, and Ls are not typically inserted.

Comment: Going that route I'm thinking of a second order LC filter with as high inductance as I can get away with within reasonable component size and a common mode choke. A ferrite-bead for good measure as well. Since I have a pseudo analog 5V rail I'm thinking maybe two LDOs one for the high current antenna driver and one for the rest. From your answer I gather most filtering should happen before the LDO, am I right in assuming I can get away with a smaller LC filter after the LDO addressing its specific switching frequency (in addition to the LCLC up front)?